# Output a two-dimensonal variable array in cplex

Tags: java, linear-programming, cplex

Currently I am trying to output a two dimensonal array of variables in CPLEX. The array is defined in the following way:

```java
IloNumVar[][] y = new IloNumVar[numJobs][]; 
for(int j=0; j<numJobs; j++){
    y[j]= cplex.numVarArray(numJobs,0, 1, IloNumVarType.Int);//ILP
}
```

After solving the ILP these variables should be printed. I tried to print them in the following way:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < numJobs; i++) {
    for(int j=0; j < y[i].length; j++){
        System.out.println(cplex.getValues(y[i][j])+ ", ");
    }
}
```

As an error I receive "CPLEX Error: object is unknown to IloCplex"

If I set j=1 only values for i=0 are printed..

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Does your code snippet really compile? Shouldn't we get an `IloNumVar` with `y[i][j]`? If that is the case, there is no overload for [getValues](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.html#getValues(ilog.concert.IloNumVar[])) that takes an `IloNumVar`.

Comment: If my answer below doesn't solve your problem, please provide a [minimal, reproducible, example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> CPLEX Error: object is unknown to IloCplex

This error usually shows up when you have not added an object to the model (i.e., that particular `IloNumVar` does not appear in any constraint nor the objective). You might want to export your model to the LP format with the [exportModel](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.10.0/ilog.odms.cplex.help/refjavacplex/html/ilog/cplex/IloCplex.html#exportModel(java.lang.String)) method to check that it is formulated correctly (i.e., as you expect).

A possible workaround would be to explicitly add all variables to the model before you call `solve()`. For example:

```
for (IloNumVar[] v : y)
    cplex.add(v);
```

With this, you should be able to query all of the `IloNumVar`'s in `y` and the error should no longer occur.

Comment: @Makoto: I *did* answer the question, but I'm working with imperfect information here. At any rate, I've observed that many times new contributors benefit from answers like this. Thanks for the feedback, though.

Comment: I've clarified my answer and added comments to the original question.